# As a private individual, what might I learn from hiring a pentester for my home network?

Tags: penetration-test

It's far from unusual for companies to hire external pentesters to probe their systems in order to expose vulnerabilities. Finding companies that cater to this market isn't difficult, and a few candidates are at the other end of just a web search.

However, it seems most or all of those companies cater to the business-to-business market, not individuals.

As an individual, assuming that I can find a reputable company that is willing to work with me, and that I am willing to pay the cost for their services, **what could I expect to learn about my home IT security by hiring a pentesting company?** Am I likely to learn anything that can't be found out simply by hooking up my network to the Internet for a few minutes and monitoring the resulting firewall logs, and looking for software updates?

Comment: You have asked the equivalent of "how long is a piece of string?" It will depend on your assets and the scope of the test. And your alternative to testing is not equivalent at all.

Comment: @schroeder Well, of course it depends on the scope of the test; it would also depend on the skills of the particular attacker (assessor). I was hoping this would be narrow enough to be answerable by focusing on categories, though. There certainly seems to be a mostly standard framework for what pentesters look for in corporate networks and systems, for example, obviously limited by the client's willingness to pay and allow access.

Comment: Your question does not include categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two primary assessment types that a penetration tester can provide: **internal** and **external** security assessments. There are many other subcategories within this classification, but for simplicity's sake, let's talk about these two primary types of penetration test.

An External Penetration Test is conducted from outside your network -- from the Internet. This simulates what an arbitrary online attacker might see, and could identify flaws in services you're running that are exposed to the Internet. For example: if you were running a web server at home, but potentially forgot to patch it, a penetration tester might be able to exploit known vulnerabilities and pivot into your home network.

An Internal Penetration Test places the security assessor inside your home network. In this case, you would either grant the pentester physical access to your home, or spin up a VM with VPN access, or something similar. The scope of this test is much different: you don't need to be running any public services to be attacked. A tester in this scenario would be able to scan your internal network, identify devices, and -- depending on your network configuration -- might even be able to sniff your network traffic.

In my experience, you probably wouldn't find much on an External test (unless you're using your home as a server host of some kind), since most people don't have any Internet-facing services. Maybe your router has a web interface that could have vulnerabilities or misconfigurations -- but more likely, the report would be relatively empty.

An Internal test, on the other hand, would almost certainly identify weaknesses in your home network. The question for you, then, is whether untrusted individuals are being given network access in your home. If they are, and you want to see what a skilled attacker might be able to pull off, this could provide some valuable insight.

In truth, if you're keeping all your systems and software up-to-date and aren't running any Internet-facing services, you're probably relatively OK from a security perspective. If this is the case, your biggest threats will be in the form of spearphishing/social engineering, or online services you use getting hacked. Don't re-use passwords (use a password manager + random passwords), and don't upload data to services without thinking about what would happen if they were breached. Utilizing full-disk encryption on your hard disks keeps you safe in case of physical theft of your computer.

Here's the really short answer: you probably wouldn't learn much from an External test, and you'd likely get compromised by a skilled attacker that's already on your Internal network. It is probably not worth the cost, but you won't know what an assessor would find without buying the assessment!